# How to subtract from mysql database after pressing html button?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to subtract 0.05 from the cash amount of a player in my database once they push a button. Here is what I got so far.

My database:

Database name: **accounts**

Table: **users**

The Column I want to affect: **cash_amount**

***Html:***

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function myAjax () {
$.ajax( { type : 'POST',
            data : { },
            url  : 'subtract5.php',              // <=== CALL THE PHP FUNCTION HERE.
            success: function ( data ) {
                alert( data );               // <=== VALUE RETURNED FROM FUNCTION.
            },
            error: function ( xhr ) {
                alert( "error" );
            }
        });
}
</script>


<button id="playbutton" onclick="myAjax();location.href='5game.html'">Play (-5&#162;)</button>
```

***Php file: (subtract5.php)***

```
<?php

 UPDATE `accounts`.`users` SET `cash_amount` = '`cash_amount` - 0.05'
```

Thanks for helping, I am kind of a noob :)

Comment: any error you are getting?

Comment: Please provide php code. This is obviously not the code, performing the update query.

Comment: No error, it's just redirecting the page, (the second onclick function)

Comment: Ben, that is the only php code i'm starting on, please supply the correct code if that is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick that's not php code, that is plain sql. I think you should read a pdo or mysqli tutorial how to execute sql statement from php.

Comment: SQL Query is wrong too. Change `UPDATE accounts.users SET cash_amount = 'cash_amount - 0.05'` To `UPDATE accounts.users SET cash_amount = cash_amount - 0.05`

Answer (score 0):

This the following code, however dont exactly copy paste it, read the comments there are a few variables you might have to change and get from the database.

```
<?php
$servername = "servarname";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbName";

// Create connection

$userid = // You must enter the user's id here.

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Fetch the existing value of the cash_amount against that particular user here. You can use the SELECT cash_amount from users where userid = $userid

$newAmount = $previousAmount - 0.05;

$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = '$newAmount'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result)
{
   echo "Query Executed Successfully!";
}
else
{
   echo mysqli_error($conn);
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: where do you see a number as a string?

Comment: cash_amount = '$newAmount'

Comment: Oh when you're in inside a string, you can use single quotes to incorporate a variable there. 
Alternatively you can also do a "some string".$variable

Comment: Nope, you are wrong. No need for the single quotes around the variable names.

Comment: Can you please try the following code and see if the works properly before making any allegations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149559/discussion-between-aaditya-damani-and-shadow).

Comment: You should really read the php manual on strings http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php search for Variable parsing and see for yourself.

Comment: Please forget my last reply. What is the user id? Should i write it equal to $_SESSION['id']; ?  Because there is a column in my database called id that supplies the user id.

Comment: So i tried it out, i think this has to do with the user id, but when i pressed the button every person in my database had negative 0.05 in their cash amount.

Comment: I fixed the negative 0.05, and made it able to subtract the 0.05. Now i have to fix it happening to everyone in the database. Plese help. Thanks.

Comment: Yes @Patrick lets understand the flow first. Your table has many users each of them have some cash amount right? Now when you try to subtract, from your logic, how would your program know which user to subtract the amount from? So we first get the userid of the person you want to make the subtraction and then we subtract the amount from his balance.

Comment: So for instance, I am trying to subtract 0.05 from Patrick's account, so I will first get the original balance in his account and then subtract 0.05 from the original balance and then UPDATE his cashamount with a new value. If you can provide your PHP file, I would be able to help you further.

Comment: Where can i provide the file?

Comment: Just copy paste your code here. Or create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try executing that request. That's nothing more than a string without quotes around it. I'm sure that PHP considers it as an error.

You should consider learning PHP and MySQL before attempting to code a project.

Comment: You should consider learning how to answer before you attempt to reply, bud. I learn by your answers. This one taught me nothing.